# Most preferred DTD (Document type declarations) and why do we need it?

Tags: html, dtd

Which one is the most preferred & commonly used DTD now a days? I don't know why do we need them.

Comment: Popularity contests are a poor way to make technology decisions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not about what is commonly used but what is [right for your site](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/14-choosing-the-right-doctype-for-your/).

See also http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/

**Update**

Here is more up to date page on the topic:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/webmaster/quick-tip-selecting-the-right-doctype/328

Comment: When you strip out the links, your answer becomes useless. Can you add some more detail in it?

Comment: Those links are to documents that are somewhat dated too.

Comment: @PiTheNumber Helpful links, I've to dig into them, anyway thanks.

Comment: The questions author did not put much effort in his question so I don't feel the need to put effort in the answer. My answer is not wrong and if you think you can give a better one feel free to do so. I will up vote you. Destructive down votes like this make me stop answer any questions at all.

Answer (score -1):

`<!DOCTYPE html>`
is common now a days, its HTML 5 DOC Type decleration 
As for XHTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```